# Why does dependency injecting a scoped instance of a DBContext and a singleton in a controller, throws an invalid operation exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an interface and it's implementation registered as a singleton service alongside a DBContext at the services container. I've used dependency injection in a controller for both of these services but it throws the following exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'DepartmentOrders.Data.OrderTypeContext' from singleton 'DepartmentOrders.ShoppingCart.ICartDB'.
```

I did not intend to make the singleton service *consume* dbcontext, and thought they would be separate services, meaning that no kind of parent-child relationship should exist, but I'm barely familiar services so I'm missing something here for sure.

If I remove any of the injections in the controller and leave one, the program works as intended.

The ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ICartDB, CartDB>();

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.AddDbContext<OrderTypeContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DP_Orders") ));
}
```

The controller:

```
ICartDB Cart;
private readonly OrderTypeContext Data;

public HomeController(OrderTypeContext _Data, ICartDB _Cart)
{
    this.Cart = _Cart;
    this.Data = _Data;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await Data.Departments.ToListAsync());
}
```

The singleton:

```
public interface ICartDB 
{
    bool Exists(int ItemId);
    bool IsEmpty();
    Dictionary<int, int> GetCart();
    void DeleteItem(string ItemId);
    void AddItem(int ItemId, int Quantity);
    void EditItem(int ItemId, int Quantity);
}
```

Comment: Do you inject an `OrderTypeContext` into your `CartDB` implementation? If so, it would be a lifetime issue, as your OrderTypeContext's (scoped) lifetime will be be shorter than the CartDB's singleton life time. Related discussion can be found on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4988)

Comment: I just checked and this is the problem.

Comment: Yes, the team added an overload for `AddDbContext` which accepts a lifetime as seen [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/commit/816f77cf92a8ef8970d439f6f421edf2e39225c0)